# Issue while Automapper Upgrade to 5.1.1

Tags: automapper, automapper-5

We were using the automapper v5.0 in our code. In our create map statement, we had a statement ->

```
m.ResolveUsing((src, o, context) => (CodeObject)context.Options.Items["test"]))
```

When we upgraded the Automapper version to 5.1.1, we are getting build error in the above statement.

Can you please suggest how to correct this with latest version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i have got the answer after going through the automapper source code. We can do it this way:

```
m => m.ResolveUsing((src, o, destMemb, context) => (CodeObject)context.Items["test"]))
```